# How to specify the file format in the DataDownload schema?

Tags: schema.org

For example, I have the description of a [Dataset](http://schema.org/Dataset) and I would like to specify if the [DataDownload](http://schema.org/DataDownload)/distribution is a xml or json file.

The property `encodingFormat` seems to be use to specify if the file is 'utf-8' or something else like 'windows-1252'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right - it's *encodingFormat* property.

Dataset [page](http://schema.org/Dataset) at Schema.org has inconspicuous comment

> This class is based upon W3C DCAT work, and benefits from collaboration around the DCAT, ADMS and VoID vocabularies. See http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/Datasets for full details and mappings

This page at wiki provides very good example of what you're looking for.

```
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Dataset" itemid="http://example.org/datasets/seismic-hazard-zones">

...
  <div itemprop="distribution" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/DataDownload">
    <i>Download:</i>
    <a href="http://example.org/downloads/seismic-hazard-zones.nt.gz">
      <meta itemprop="encodingFormat" content="text/plain" />
      <meta itemprop="contentUrl" content="http://example.org/downloads/seismic-hazard-zones.nt.gz" />
      <meta itemprop="inLanguage" content="en" />
      <span itemprop="description">compressed N-Triples dump</span>,
      <span itemprop="datePublished" content="2011-08-12">August 12, 2011</meta>
      <span itemprop="contentSize" content="13.9">(13.97MB)</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So as you see

> encodingformat: text/plain

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. Just to make sure of my understanding, the encodingFormat could be `"text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1"` if I want to specify the charset of the file. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. Since *encodingFormat* maps to *dcterms:format* (http://dublincore.org/documents/2012/06/14/dcmi-terms/?v=terms#terms-format) which includes MIME types.